# Create list from custom template using csom, c#

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I would like to create a list based on a template (.stp uploaded to the list template gallery), it almost works with this code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("<Your Site URL>");
    Web site = context.Web;            
    context.Load(site);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //Create a List.
    ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo;
    List list;

    listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.Title = "<Your Title>";
    listCreationInfo.Description = "<Your Description>";

    ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "<Your Template Name>");
    listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
    listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

    list = site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

It display this error:
[image: Error text]

This is were i found the code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107570/how-do-i-create-a-new-list-from-a-list-template-client-object-model

Can anybody help me? thx.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Where I am trying to create a list using a custom list template through CSOM. In my case it is a custom Wiki Page library. I am assigning the featureID and ListTemplateTypeKind of the template to the ListCreationInformation. The code just works fine without any error. However new library gets created with default Wiki Page library features and not that of my custom template. I am using Office 365. Did you get a break through and if yes I would really appreciate if you could share the solution. Thanks
-Pankaj

Answer (score 3):

In your example, while  retrieving `List Template` at the line:

```
var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "<Your Template Name>");
```

the error `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException` will occur since `ListTemplates` collection have to be requested explicitly, for example:

```
context.Load(site,s => s.ListTemplates );
```

Below is provided the fixed example:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
{
     //context.Credentials = credentials;
     var site = context.Web;
     context.Load(site,s => s.ListTemplates );
     context.ExecuteQuery();

     var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
     {
           Title = "<Your Title>",
           Description = "<Your Description>"
     };

     var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "<Your Template Name>");
     listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
     listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

     site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Almost there, now it breaks at: ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "Dokumentbibliotek3.0");

Display error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll Additional information: Sequence contains no elements 

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

this is an old question but adding the reason why this is not working for benefit of others

the reason this breaks on the below line is because this `site.ListTemplates` does not contain the custom list template
`ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "Dokumentbibliotek3.0");`

to get the custom list template use the below line 
`var listTemplates = context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(context.Web);
context.load(listTemplates);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListTemplate listTemplate = listTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "Dokumentbibliotek3.0");`

rest of the code remains the same

Answer (score 1):

`First();` is used to get first element from LINQ C# query

Have you tried adding namespace `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: Thank you, got me further. Now it display this error: 

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Which line of code is breaking? It seems you're not using `Load()` before calling `ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: It breaks at: ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(listTemp => listTemp.Name == "KlasseSiteMenu3.0.1"); 
How should i include Load() in my code?