# Creating List based on List template with content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, client-object-model

Now I could successfult create list based on list template 
but when i saved my list template i could say "Include Content"
but when the list created by this code it was empty with no content
any ideas ?

```
function createLists() {


var context = new SP.ClientContext('/groupcompanies/AAC');
var web = context.get_web();

var listInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
listInfo.set_title('ListCreation Test');
listInfo.set_description('photo gallery picture library');
listInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.pictureLibrary); 
listInfo.set_templateFeatureId("00BFEA71-52D4-45B3-B544-B1C71B620109");
var list = web.get_lists().add(listInfo);




context.load(list);

context.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {
        console.log(String.format('List {0} has been created successfully',list.get_title()));
     },
     function (sender, args) {
        console.log("%c Ops!" + args.get_message(),"color:red;");
     }
);

}//end createLists
```

Comment: An alternative approach (hence not an answer) would be to provision the new lists using only code; would make your solution independent of any other assets that may or may not exist no the server, making the solution much more resilient if you needed to re-deploy, make updates, or deploy to multiple environments

Answer (score 2):

The FeatureId `00BFEA71-52D4-45B3-B544-B1C71B620109` is used for Custom lists. You need to check the FeatureId of your custom template. To determine FeatureId property, you could save your list as a template, then go to List Template Gallery page `(/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx)` and find the Feature Id value of the corresponding.
list. see the answer by ***Vadim Gremyachev*** for more information: [How can one create a custom list in JSOM based on a custom list template (STP) in 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77582/how-can-one-create-a-custom-list-in-jsom-based-on-a-custom-list-template-stp-i)

Comment: thats the post that i followed i already did and i got tottaly new created list no fields no contents 

see thats my list templates gallery and the same featureID shown
http://1drv.ms/1FtYzxd

Comment: The one which is selected in the screenshot has GUID ending with 100 but you are using the one ending with 109.

Comment: yes its the other one on the top ending with 109 i tried both of them with diffirent GUID and templateType 
but the smame result 
only creating list empty new one

Comment: i think this post is a solution but with Csom 
i dunno how to use it 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104611/create-list-from-custom-template-using-csom-c

u've any idea ?